# Undoing the distributive property with matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

If you have the expression $ \boldsymbol{\theta}^T \sigma^{-2} \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{X}^T \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1} \boldsymbol{X}$, how could you factor out the common $\boldsymbol{X}^T$? Assume that $\boldsymbol{X}$ and $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}$ are matrices, $\boldsymbol{\theta}$ is a vector, and $\sigma$ is a scalar. This is actually a statistics problem but I think the idea should apply to any general case for matrices, vectors, and scalars.

My instinct is that we can do something like this: $\boldsymbol{X}^T(\boldsymbol{\theta}^T \sigma^{-2}\boldsymbol{\theta} + \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^{-1})\boldsymbol{X}$ but I have my doubts this will actually work because obviously order matters when you are multiplying matrices. I am guessing that the way I have done it, the first term inside the parentheses will not properly get distributed. I am also not sure about the $\boldsymbol{X}$ I have placed outside the parentheses. I think it works for the second term in the parentheses since we multiply right-to-left but it won't be in the right position for the first term.

I have looked up the distributive law for matrices but the examples typically given assume that there is are just two matrices being added, i.e. $\boldsymbol{A}(\boldsymbol{B} + \boldsymbol{C}) = \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{B} + \boldsymbol{A} \boldsymbol{C}$. So I am not sure how to apply this in my case.

Comment: There is no such rule. If you have $AB + CA$, there is no way to combine terms or simplify. Your instinct is, unfortunately, plain wrong. You can factor out the $\sigma$ and write the first term as $\sigma^{-2}y^\top y$, where $y=X\theta$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ok, that makes sense. I feel kind of stupid now. So I suppose either of these are valid? $AB + AC = A(B + C)$ or $BA + CA = (B + C)A$?

Comment: Yes, those are correct.